# Установка связей в таблице mySQL

Tags: mysql

Ребята, помогите, разобраться на пальцах. 
(ситуацию упростил до самой сути)

Есть две таблицы. Первая со списком товаров. Назовем ее `productTable` в ней есть колонка `productID` и остальные. Есть вторая таблица с комментариями `commentTable` и конечно тоже с колонкой `poductID2`(чтобы не путаться). Теперь нужно установить связи таблиц. Предполагаю поставить on-update: cascade и on-delete:cascade Дальше небольшая путаница, в этом и суть вопроса.

В какой таблице эту связь нужно устанавливать?

Я иду в `productTable` и там ставлю связь `productID => poductID2` или наоборот в `commentTable` и связь `poductID2 => productID` ?

Comment: Связь указывает на первичный ключ в другой, следовательно второй вариант

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Продукт без комментария существовать может? запросто. Значит, и ссылаться ему ни на что не нужно.

А комментарий без продукта? чёта вряд ли. Значит, ему ссылаться нужно.

Значит, **commentTable (productID2) references productTable (productID)**.

Comment: В таком варианте, если я удаляю продукт - комменты тоже удалятся (при каскаде). А комменты удалять можно спокойно? Правильно? (извините, за глупость, так все и стоит сейчас, но почему-то задумался и одолела паранойя)

Comment: Конечно... если только на них не ссылается кто-то ещё.

Answer (score 0):

Из дочерней таблицы в родительскую.